# Is the current PHP foreach item the last one in the Iterator?

Tags: php

When iterating over an iterator in Php, for example symfonys finder (`composer require symfony/finder`):

```
$files = \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::create()
            ->in('searchdir')
            ->directories()
            ->depth(0)
            ->sortByType();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    //is $file the last element?
}
```

What's the best way to check if `$file` is the last item in the `$files` iterator?

Comment: If you wrote your own class, which extends from `iterator` you could make a method to check if the current element is the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the two answeres I received to my question are blatantly wrong, let me answer with what I found out:

## Method 1

You could get the last key like this:

```
$last = null;
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
   $last = $key;
}
```

and then compare the key in your iteration:

```
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === $last) {
        ....
    }
}
```

## Method 2

If your iterator implements the `seek` method and is `Countable` (or has a `count`-method), you could also obtain the last key like this:

```
$iterator->seek(count($iterator) - 1); 
$last = $iterator->key();
```

This seems like the cleaner solution at first, but according to my test with symfonys finder class (5000 files, tested both methods 100 times), this is ~3 times as slow as using the foreach function. Could an expert chime in why?

## Method 3

The solution I am now using, as it creates as little overhead as possible is this (if the iterator is not `Countable` (most are), use [iterator_count](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.iterator-count.php) instead of `count`):

```
$index = 0;
$length = count($iterator);
foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    $index++;
    if ($index == $length) {
        // last item!
    }
}
```

Comment: For Method 3, you can reduce the code by one line by using `if(++$index==$length)`. Also this works for a plain old array too, it doesn't have to be an iterator!

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating something and you actually care about the index of the item you could go with the classic for structure:

```php
for($i=0; $i<count($iterator);$i++) {
    if($i==count($iterator)-1) {
        // You reached the last item
    }
}
```

Or also using $key=>$value like this:

```php
foreach($iterator as $iteratorKey=>$iteratorValue) {
    if($iteratorKey==count($iterator)-1) {
        // You reached the last item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$cachingIterator = new \CachingIterator($iterator, \CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE);

while ($iterator->valid()) {
    $cachingIterator->next();
}

$lastKey = $cachingIterator->key();
$lastCurrentValue = $cachingIterator->current();
```

This is implemented in [Last operation](https://github.com/loophp/collection/blob/master/src/Operation/Last.php) of [loophp/collection](https://github.com/loophp/collection).